# Getting values from simplexmlelement object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having trouble with converting my simplexmlelement object to variables. This is my xml output:

```
<affiliate_signup_response>
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Duplicate Affiliate Contact</message>
  <affiliate_id>0</affiliate_id>
</affiliate_signup_response>
```

Now i've searched the net and found out that I have to do something like this to get the output:

```
(string) $xml[0]->succes;
(string) $xml->succes;
(string) $xml->affiliate_signup_response->succes;
```

I just can't seem to get the right response and am probaly missing the right clue into making this work. I really hope this is not a dumb question.

If create a foreach loop with $key and $value this is the output:

```
key: success value: false
key: message value: Duplicate Affiliate Contact
key: affiliate_id value: 0
```

Comment: In all your examples, you've spelled "success" wrong. `$xml->success` and `$xml[0]->success` should work fine.

Comment: such a simple error. I thought I really checked everything before asking

Comment: Sometimes, you just need a second pair of eyes! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$str = <<<XML
<affiliate_signup_response>
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Duplicate Affiliate Contact</message>
  <affiliate_id>0</affiliate_id>
</affiliate_signup_response>
XML;


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
//var_dump($xml);
$success = $xml->success;
$message = $xml->message;
$affiliate_id = $xml->affiliate_id;

echo $success."<br />";
echo $message."<br />";
echo $affiliate_id."<br />";
```

Comment: I can't believe it. The solution was one simple typo pointed out by another user in a comment.